# Dynamically set the file path for static files in the index.html file in a React app via a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, configuration

I'm trying to dynamically set the file paths to the static files (js & css) in the index.html file of my create-react-app such that they can point to different sub-directories depending on what I set in a settings.json file.

**Example:**
If I set the base_url in my settings.json file like this:

```
{
   "BASE_PATH_URL": "/subdirec1"
}
```

I expect the file path in my index.html file to be like this:

```
<script src="/subdirec1/static/vendors/js/core/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, you can use webpack variables that you can set within the webpack config object, which themselves come from a .json/.js file.

[This](https://medium.com/dailyjs/inserting-variables-into-html-and-javascript-with-webpack-80f33625edc6) is the example you can use if you're using webpack!

WARNING: Don't use the command below before reading up on it, because it will make a big mess of files you might not understand yet!

Since you're using create-react-app, I think it uses webpack under the hood but you need to `npm run eject` it to have more complete access to its configuration!

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there no another way to do this without having to eject the React app.